# What do you need to do to get a First Aid medal in ME3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What do you need to do to get a First Aid medal in ME3 multiplayer?
I know that it is not related to:

- reviving someone in your party
- using medi gel to pick yourself up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is for reviving teammates. If you revive enough teammates you will get a badge during the match.  It isn't simply for popping just one up, it is 5 for the first round medal.

Comment: You are right.  You need to revive teammates at least 5 times to get the metal.

Comment: @Roger Ye heavy meTal... :D